# On changing enabled property of dropdownlist in asp.net CSS/jquery doesn't work.

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

i have `dropdownlist` in web page having `enabled` property `false`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpBldGp" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control chzn-select-deselect"  runat="server" >
```

its style is looking like as

[image: Client side searching dropdown]

but when at server side i change its property `Enabled="True"` on `button_Click` event then its `CSS` gone away and only simple `dropdownlist` appears

i also added this code to apply server side `cssClass`

```
drpBldGp.CssClass = "form-control chzn-select-deselect";
```

I need your suggestions and help that what to do.

thanks in advance

Comment: At some part of application if you are trying to add **chzn-select-deselect** this **CSS** through javascript or Jquery then surely at postback it reset to its actual markup.

Comment: @Suprabhat, please provide me solution what to do?

Comment: Didn't it worked on adding this`drpBldGp.CssClass = "form-control chzn-select-deselect"` from codebehind ?

Comment: @Suprabhat, no it didn't work.

Comment: I have added an answer `drpBldGp.CssClass = "form-control chzn-select-deselect"` this line is working properly in my solution.